# Applying encapsulation in my bus ticketing system java

Tags: java, oop

How can I insert oop of encapsulation in my code in java? I'm new at programming and really don't know where I[enter image description here][1] can insert the encapsulation into my code. Or maybe help me to put encapsulation in my code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Ruben, Welcome to the community. Please don't post an answer to extend your question. If you need to add more information just edit your question and add it.

Comment: OOP is all about defining objects with their functionality. For example, in you code you have a user. Here you could create a class that contains username, password, etc.. and then some functions for it for example to check the password.

Answer (score 1):

You can use access modifiers in order to apply encapsulation. Encapsulation is all about binding data together to a single unit. As an example you can make your instance variables private. I could not see any instance variables here.

Instance Variables: Variables declared outside the methods but inside the class